# Copy all data from external excel file for specific ID

Tags: excel

Let me explain this weird topic.

i have one sheet like:

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <th>ID</th>
    <th>Country</th>
    <th>City</th>
    <th>Code</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>AA_1</td>
    <td>Germany</td>
    <td>Berlin</td>
    <td>1234</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>BB_2</td>
    <td>Poland</td>
    <td>Woclaw</td>
    <td>2345</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

And another like

```html
<table>
      <tr>
        <th>ID</th>
        <th>Country</th>
        <th>City</th>
        <th>Code</th>
      </tr>
    </table>
```

I've created snippet for show my sheet

And now what's problem. If my file A.xlsx is filled and B.xlsxis empty  only with heads I want to do something like:
If in my B file I'll fill ID Columnt for example with: AA_1 i want to have autocomplete for rest columns ( all from A file ).

How can I achieve it?

Comment: autocomplete where? excel or HTML?

Comment: excel not html.

Answer (score 0):

Sheet1:

[image]

Sheet2:

[image]

Select cells `B2, C2 and D2` in `Sheet2`, then press `Ctrl + Shift + down arrow`. Then enter the below formula in formula bar and then press `Ctrl + enter`,

```
=IFERROR(INDEX(Sheet1!B:B,MATCH($A2,Sheet1!$A:$A,0),1),"")
```

Now it will autofill whenever you enter data in `column A` of `sheet2`